# Video player with bookmarks

Tags: linux, video, free-software, bookmarks

Does there exist a video player for Linux that has bookmarks? That is, I would like to watch a video, close the player and then go back watching from the same moment when I reopen the file, or from some other moment that I bookmarked. I think that VLC has something similar, but am not completely sure as it didn't also quite work for me. There were also no bookmarks as such.

Comment: Setting `Preferences > Interface > Playlists and Instances > Continue Playback?` to `Always` does not work?

Comment: `mpv` has the option `save-position-on-quit`. But I'm pretty sure you can do that in `vlc` as well.

Comment: Thanks, but still not quite the concept of bookmarks, when you can set several bookmarks in one video and come back later.

Comment: There are some scripts/plugins for mpv that allow you to set bookmarks and resume. There may be separate plugins for each function. Google `mpv bookmarks`